# JTree view under High Contrast Mode

Tags: java, swing, jtree, section508, high-contrast

I have one issue related to JTree swing component,
I want to use JTree under Windows high contrast Mode, but it never shows tree nodes according to windows High contrast theme.

Jtree view Under **Normal Mode**

[image]

Jtree view Under **High Contrast Mode**

[image]

Eclipse Package Explorer view Under **Normal Mode**

[image]

Eclipse Package Explorer view Under **High Contrast Mode**

[image]

I want to make my applications jtree view same as eclipse's "high contrast" view.

Can anybody guide on this??
I am trying to write a logic like:

// calling this On application load - or via some kind of listener

```
Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(); 
Boolean highContrast = (Boolean)toolkit.getDesktopProperty( "win.highContrast.on" ); 
boolean flag=highContrast.booleanValue();
    if(flag){
    // do stuff for high contrast
    }
    else{
    // show in normal mode
    }
```

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented this with the help of toolkit calls [pscode.org/prop/form.html](http://pscode.org/prop/form.html) - get Changed font and font size details and apply to jtree

Answer (score 2):

According to this [issue](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4268204) is this bug in Swing L&F implementation. There is possible to accept this by modifying Windows L&F and provide it as own, or use different L&F which supports this.